# Import a c++ DLL to VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-studio, dllimport

i can't import a C/C++ DLL to a VB.NET project. In the headerfile of the DLL i have the following:

```
IPCONFIG_DLLEXPORT  int     __cdecl     IPConfig_GetDeviceList( __in uint32_t count_buffer_entries, __inout_ecount_opt(count_buffer_entries) IPConfig_Info* buffer_list, __out uint32_t* count_avaialble_entries );
```

with the following structure:

```
typedef struct IPConfig_Info
{
uint64_t    Mac;
char ManufacturerName[64];
char ModelName[64];
char Serialnumber[64];
char UserDefinedName[64];
char ManufacturerSpecificInformation[64];

char AdapterName[64];
char FirmwareVersion[64];

uint32_t    IPAddress;
uint32_t    Subnetmask;
uint32_t    Gateway;
} IPConfig_Info;
```

at the VB side i am doing this:

```
NotInheritable Class Config_Api
Public Structure IPConfig_Info
    Public Mac As UInt64
    Public ManufacturerName() As Char
    Public ModelName() As Char
    Public Serialnumber() As Char
    Public UserDefinedName() As Char
    Public ManufacturerSpecificInformation() As Char
    Public AdapterName() As Char
    Public FirmwareVersion() As Char
    Public IPAddress As UInt32
    Public Subnetmask As UInt32
    Public Gateway As UInt32
End Structure
<DllImport("ipconfig_api_win32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Public Shared Function IPConfig_GetDeviceList(ByVal count_buffer_entries As UInt32, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)> buffer_list() As IPConfig_Info, ByRef count_avaialble_entries As UInt32) As Integer
End Function
End Class
```

and calling all this with:

```
        Dim elements(5) As Config_Api.IPConfig_Info
    Dim availableEntrys As UInt32 = 0
        Dim posresp As Integer = Config_Api.IPConfig_GetDeviceList(nubCam, elements, availableEntrys)
```

but it is not working. Has anyone an idea. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Not working" is a pretty general term. What error exactly are you getting?

Comment: Your struct is wrong. You need to tell the marshaller how long the arrays are. `String` with `ByValTStr` is your friend. `char` in C++ is 8 bits wide. Not so in .net. Doesn't look like a safe array to me. Probably many more errors.

Comment: like this i get "wrong Parameter. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))". When i change to <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> svhost32.exe is crashing, and i get: Additional information: The duration has detected a fatal error. Error Message: "0x74707e0d" in thread "0xdf4". Error Code: 0xC0000005. This error could be a problem in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common causes of this bug are Mars Haller errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may damage the stack.

Comment: There is just no point in pinvoking a wonky DLL that you cannot debug.  This info is also available through the System.Configuration namespace and the Win32_NetworkAdapterSetting WMI class.  Use the [WMI Code Creator utility](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) to experiment with queries and letting it generate the code you need in a VB.NET app.

Comment: In My opinion, is the main problem that i have a pointer to an array of a structrue which is an inout variable and i don't know how to build this in c#, there is also no tut for such a complex case. Tahnk you all anyway!

Comment: There are loads of tutorials and examples of building what is a relatively simple struct. I've even told you the one key things you are missing, `ByValTStr`. Your trial and error approach is not constructive.